# Prepend JS var into HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to prepend a JSON value to html in the value attribute of an input tag and pass it through a form.

```html
<div class="results"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
  var url = "MYID";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    var entry = data.feed.entry;

    var result = entry.filter(entry => entry.gsx$status.$t.length < 4); 

    var form = "<form class='gform' method='post' data-email='MYEMAIL' action='MYGOOGLEAPP'><input id='createObject' name='Submit1' type='submit' value='submit' />"
    var formend = "</form>"

    $(result).each(function() {
      // Column names will only pull from status
      $('.results').prepend(
        '<H1>INCOMING</H1>',
        '<table>',
        '<tr><th>DESCRIPTION:</th><th>PRICE:</th><th>QTY</th></tr>',
        '<tr><td>' + this.gsx$description.$t + '</td><td>' + this.gsx$price.$t + '</td><td>' + this.gsx$qty.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<br>',
        '<tr><td>ORDER TOTAL:</td><td>$' + this.gsx$total.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>STATUS:</td><td>' + this.gsx$status.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>REG NUMBER:</td><td>' + this.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>CUSTOMER:</td><td>' + this.gsx$customer.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>SHIPPING ADDRESS:</td><td>' + this.gsx$address.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>DATE CREATED:</td><td>' + this.gsx$date.$t + '</td></tr>',
        '</table>',
        '<br>',
        form,
        "<input type='checkbox'  id='data'  name='data' class='selector' value=" + this.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t + ">test</input>",
        formend
      );
    });

  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#createObject').click(function() {
      var ar = [];
      $('.selector').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          ar.push({
            reg: $(this).attr('value')
          });
        }
      });
      alert(JSON.stringify(ar));
    });
  });
</script>
```

So $(document) function works (tested it with another button). But the information in var ar is not passing as part of the form input. So its just spitting out blank data. Given that I'm playing with prepend to make this work am I've ran over my code to check for errors in the JS to HTML but I can't find any issue. So have I messed something up in the part where it passes to the form?

This is what it returns: 
{"result":"success","data":"{\"Submit1\":[\"submit\"]}"}

Thanks all!

Comment: What is is the JSON you receive back from the GET?

Comment: [] if null. [{"reg":"2"}] if checked. Reg being the assigned ID in the script and 2 being the value of the json info returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bobjoe for the help, eventually found that I could create a var with the html to append and it worked. Here is the code:

```
var input = "<input type='checkbox'  id='data'  name='data' class='selector' value='"
var inputend = "'/>"

   $(result).each(function(){
    // Column names will only pull from status
     $('.results').prepend(
        '<H1>INCOMING PURCHASE ORDER</H1>',
        '<table>',
        '<tr><th>DESCRIPTION:</th><th>PRICE:</th><th>QTY</th></tr>',
        '<tr><td>'+this.gsx$description.$t+'</td><td>'+this.gsx$price.$t+'</td><td>'+this.gsx$qty.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<br>',
        '<tr><td>ORDER TOTAL:</td><td>$'+this.gsx$total.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>STATUS:</td><td>'+this.gsx$status.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>REG NUMBER:</td><td>'+this.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>CUSTOMER:</td><td>'+this.gsx$customer.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>SHIPPING ADDRESS:</td><td>'+this.gsx$address.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>DATE CREATED:</td><td>'+this.gsx$date.$t+'</td></tr>',
        '</table>',
        '<br>',
        form+input+this.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t+inputend,
        formend
        );
  });
```

This provide the data intended in the results:

{"result":"success","data":"{\"data\":[\"4\"],\"Submit1\":[\"submit\"]}"}

Answer (score 1):

To use `each` to iterate over an array, you should use it like

```
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
// Column names will only pull from status
```

And then use `value` instead of `this`

I think the issue you are getting is because of how jQuery deals with `this`. 
To quote from their page

> (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.)

[jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: So replace all instances of 'this' with 'value'? E.g. this.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t becomes value.gsx$regisnbrtx.$t? Why would that cause an issue with the form grabbing data?